# How to retrieve all data from Android Firebase database databaseRef->userID->uniqueKey

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is the Firebase database:

ExchangeItemsData:  -> reference

lhmuj6n3g6Su1rv7XJLq5tV62yr2 -> userId

-LQQ7scByWcswW2VIPM5  -> UniqueKey inserted by .push().getKey();

// below is the data under the uniquekey

exchangeProductName: 
"Pen"

imageUrl: 
"https://firebasestoragse.googleapdfis.codfm/v04df/b/dbin..."

phoneNo: 
5465464

productDesc: 
"Used"

productName: 
"GelPen"

userID: 
"lhmuj6n3g6Su1rv7XJLq5tV62yr2"

I need to show all data of every user in this ExchangeItemsData reference. I've tried many ways but i failed. If anyone can help me out here it would be so nice of you.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please remember that SO is not a code-writing service. Please edit the question to provide the source code that got you nearest to your goal, and explain what the output was at that point. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all those values that belong to all users, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference ref = rootRef.child("ExchangeItemsData");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot dSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String imageUrl = ds.child("imageUrl").getValue(String.class);
                String phoneNo = ds.child("phoneNo").getValue(String.class);
                String productDesc = ds.child("productDesc").getValue(String.class);
                String productName = ds.child("productName").getValue(String.class);
                String userID = ds.child("userID").getValue(String.class);
                Log.d(TAG, productName);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
    }
};
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output in the logcat will be all the product names of all products of all users.

Comment: This is the easiest way so far. Thank you very much @Alex Mamo

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to retrieve values from your database

```
public class Demo extends Activity{
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
String currentUId;
DatabaseReference usersDb;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

    mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    currentUId=mAuth.getUid();        
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ExchangeItemsData");

    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists() && dataSnapshot.hasChildren()){
                for (DataSnapshot userId : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    if(!userId.getKey().equals(currentUId)) {
                        usersDb.child(userId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1) {
                                if(dataSnapshot1.hasChildren()){
                                    for (DataSnapshot userKey : dataSnapshot1.getChildren()) {

                                        String exchangeProductName = dataSnapshot1.child(userKey).child("exchangeProductName").getValue().toString();
                                        String imageUrl = dataSnapshot1.child(userKey).child("imageUrl").getValue().toString();
                                        String phoneNo = dataSnapshot1.child(userKey).child("phoneNo").getValue().toString();
                                        String productDesc = dataSnapshot1.child(userKey).child("productDesc").getValue().toString();
                                        String productName = dataSnapshot1.child(userKey).child("productName").getValue().toString();
                                        String userID = dataSnapshot1.child(userKey).child("userID").getValue().toString();

                                        //From here do whatever you want to do with those values
                                }      
                            }
                        }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: this code doesn't work either . Thanks for your suggestion though @Shehroz